# Ebay free domestic shipping error

Tags: c#, ebay-api

I am submitting 4 domestic shipping methods to Ebay using the C# dll. 3 of them are free and one is not.
I am getting this error, which doesn't appear in the documentation (or I can't find it)

> Warning: Free postage is only applicable for the first postage
>   service. Free postage will not be applied for this service. You must
>   enter a postage cost.

I tried submitting the free delivery services first, but it keeps telling me this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was actually two things:

1. You can just submit one shipping service as free.
2. Free shipping service must be the first one in the list.